# Remote Validation or Jquery ajax call shoud in ASP MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I wonder that what is the best method to valid the form in ASP MVC.

I have used Jquery Ajax to check `Username` exits in my database. So the problem is when i submit a form, this method need me click to the `Username` field to execute `onblur` function ajax call, it doesn't show previous error message.

With `Remote Validation`, it execute when i leave or focus out the `Username`. But the problem with this way is i can't manage the error message such as :
`The username must be at least 3 charaters....` or `The username already taken`.

Anyone can give me a suggestion or some link how to valid a form `ontime` (it means when user leave out the field and go ahead to next field, like this page: http://yame.vn/TaiKhoan/DangKy ) ?

Comment: Can you post a sample on jsfiddle

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i prevent User click the button to submit form if specify field is not valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100819/how-can-i-prevent-user-click-the-button-to-submit-form-if-specify-field-is-not-v)

Comment: @PKKG I try to do with your way, but it's not work.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$("#UserName").focusout(function(event){
     var name = $(this).attr('value');
       if(name.length>=3)
       {
    searchCustomer();//Function containing your ajax call
    }
else
{
  //Show error message of length less than 3
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For Fix Your Problem You Can Use This Solution:

1. Create A JsonResult Or Action Result Method On Your Controller:

   ```
       [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult GetUserNameExistant([Bind(Include = "UserName")] User user)
   {

       var user= repository.List("").Count(c => c.user== user.UserName);
       if (!user.Equals(0))
       {
            //This User Found
           return Json("This UserName Exist!", JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
       }
       //This UserName Not Found On DB
       return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```
2. In Your Domain Class Add This Line Code Above Your Property:

   [Remote("GetUserNameExistant", "User", HttpMethod = "Post")]