# ASP.NET MVC, solution for transfering validation messages from service layer validation to view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC's built in model validation using DataAnnotations attributes works very well, and speeds up development a lot. There are, however, many cases where validation cannot be handled in the presentation layer of the application, for instance checking the database for already existing values of a unique property.

I am looking for a solution to this problem that fulfills the following requirements:

- Compatible with NInject (and other DI methods).
- Does not break SoC. The service layer must remain totally unaware of the presentation layer.
- Is automatic. Causes a minimum of extra code in (at least) the presentation layer. Think `[ValidateServiceLayer]` on the action method.
- Adheres to the DRY principle. Minimal code copying.
- Assigns the validation message to the correct property (when needed).
- Allows other validation messages to be added, both before and after running.

Extra points for these features:

- Gracefully catches exceptions and displays user friendly error message.
- Easy usage. (NuGet package?)

I have some ideas for how to implement this myself, but before I go off inventing the wheel I would like to know if it has already been perfected by someone else. Anyone run into something like this?

Comment: **[Are you are looking for remote Validation? No need to add Nuget.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18104060/2015869)**

Comment: @PKKG: Interesting, I had not run into Remote Validation before. I get the feeling it does not really fit my purpose, but I have to examine it a little closer before I can be sure. Anyway, could be quite useful in other circumstances!

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly use the RemoteAttribute and that is a legitimate solution but I sometimes opt for a different approach. I'm not sure this is the best solution but it works out for me and I thought that it's maybe worth mentioning.

Each one of my model classes inherits from a base model that looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
   private ModelStateDictionary _modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
   public ModelStateDictionary ModelState
   {
      get
      {
         return _modelState;
      }
      set
      {
         _modelState = value;
      }
   }
}
```

This way in my controller I can do something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUser(user model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       model.ModelState = ModelState;
       _userService.Update(model);
   }
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       // Edit user was successful - No validation issues in business logic.
       return View("Users"); 
   }
   return View(model);
}
```

So because we added the ModelState as a property to all your models you can now manipulate it in your service logic via your model instance. For example if validation issue is raised in your service you can do:

```
model.ModelState.AddModelError("Property Name", "Error Text");
```

The only overhead here is that in your controller action you check for ModelState.IsValid twice, once before you call your service and once after you call it.

Like I said I'm not sure this is perfect but it works for us. It's up to you to decide what is working best for you.

NOTE: You will have to add reference to System.Web.Mvc assembly to your service layer because ModelStateDictionary class resides in there, but I don't think that is an issue.

Comment: Thank you. This seems like a good approach over all, but in my case, the service is not supposed to come in contact with my view models, which are part of the presentation layer in our solution.

Comment: @NicklasForss The service doesn't have to come in contact with your view models at all. I'm assuming you have some way of converting view models to domain models probably via AutoMapper? If so then ModelState will also map over just like any other property...

Comment: @NicklasForss Even better make your domain models inherit from the base model containing ModelState property and then once you map your view model to your domain model then just attach the ModelState to it. It's actually 1 more line of code...

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC provides a mechanism that can make a remote server call in order to validate form field without posting the entire form to the server. The mechanism called **Remote Validation**.

Please take a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: It seems that the RemoteAttribute could fit the bill. I am a little put off by all the "magic strings" required for it to work, though.